# How to trigger measurements in Pyvisa?

Tags: python, measure, gpib

I have a question concerning pyvisa, a Python Library for GPIB communication. My old HP 9825 program for a HP 5342A Microwave counter should be replaced by Python. How can I translate the trigger command to the Pyvisa interface?
9825 program:

```
0: wrt 702, "AUSR7T1ST2"
1: trg 702;red 702,A;dsp A; wait 500
2: gto 1
3: end
```

The important line is line #2. I tried to use MYDEV.trigger() an MYDEV.read() in Pyvisa but then I'll only get a timeout.

So how can I translate the trg 702 command to Pyvisa?

Thank you very much!

Peter

Comment: Can you not just use the write function?

Comment: No,
I tried the MYDEV.write("") and then I got a time out while reading the value.